# Cleartype font / text rendering in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Here is a sample VCL application containing just a TEdit control.

[image: VCL]

If you compile a similar Firemonkey (FMX) application you will notice this:

[image: FMX]

(The small L letter is jumping around like crazy)

On my research i found [this](https://plus.google.com/+FredAhrens/posts/QZBP23tX1D3) G+ post which results in:

[image]

As you can see the result is better.

The jumping is gone. However the TCircle isn't rendered very nicely.

After some more research i found out that using 
`initialization GlobalUseDX := False;` has a better output:

[image]

Occasionally there is still some "letter hopping" going on but it's a better result. However it seems there is some background color behind the small L's (yellowish).

Does anyone know a better way to achieve ClearType-like font rendering using the latest Firemonkey?

Comment: It's actually a very complicated issue. Have you ever written a text renderer, working on three or four different graphics APIs, accounting for spacing with antialiased variable-width fonts? There's a reason many other similar renderers - including some by Microsoft - have similar problems. I saw a bug on OSX quite like this just the other day (with the letter 'r', not 'l'.) IMO, unless your users are commonly going to enter in a hundred Ls in a row, it is unlikely to be a very important issue.

Comment: @David H - FireMonkey **is** the target platform.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because then you end up doing things like rendering with GDI, grabbing the bitmap, converting the format, and loading it back into GPU memory. Plus other problems. Or, in short, the same reason Direct2D/DirectWrite doesn't do this and has its own layer (and don't forget many people complain about its text rendering too.)

Comment: I can see that criticism is off limits here. My comment has gone. Never mind.