# Delphi Android Text render bug?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, text-rendering, delphi-xe8

So I'm working with Delphi XE-8 on Android, using a thread for work in the background. And I have a timer updating a label for the clock from the mainthread (maybe there is a more efficient way to do this).

Now when I start my app on Android, randomly the characters for the clock are being shrunk in size or placed above or below where the character should be. This happens for the same characters during the lifetime of the App, when I close and restart the App it could be different characters. Often a number has the size of an exponant, sometimes the character is missing at all. And another time the bug doesn't appear at all... It happens about 1 out of 4-5 times.

With the picture (below) the '5' is being placed halfway up in the label, the 2 is invisible (maybe entirely above or under the visible label).

[image]

Code for the clock looks like this:

```
procedure TPage0Form.ClockTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClockTimer.Interval := 1000;
  Page0Form.lb_Clock.Text:= ( TimeToStr(Time));
end;
```

So I have tried multiple things. 
 1. Place the clock in a thread, update to UI using sync calls.
 2. Use Bitmaps instead of a label (same issue).
 3. Play around with the label's settings, labelsize, textsize, fonts, textAlignment, margins, padding etc.
But all to no avail.

I am using multiple Android devices with the required (and some of them not) processors, and the bug appears on all of them.

Is there a logical explanation (am I doing something fundamentally wrong) and how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Edit: This also happens with XE6 and XE7...
Edit2: I also tried using:

```
FMX.Types.GlobalUseGDIPlusClearType
FMX.Types.GlobalUseDirect2D 
FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas
```

None improved the situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579189/cleartype-font-text-rendering-in-firemonkey

Comment: @Zam I Tried various Initialization Global variables but to no avail. I will keep an eye out on the linked question in case a fitting answer emerges.

Comment: This is impossible. I have been programming with Delphi on Android for years and never seen anything like this. If you just have a program with a timer and a label do you get the same thing? Do you have an example program I could try?

Comment: Im trying to create a reproducible program with the error, sadly today everyone is out of the office and I have my hands full on other tasks.

Might should have added that in the background task there are also UI updates being performed (also to the label for the clock), all of these are being synchronized to the mainthread. I guess this could affect the case.

@DougRudd If I just use a plain Timer that updates the clock, it displays everything fine.

Comment: Why should you need to update the clock in something other than the main thread? Besides, every answer on stackoverflow says that you need to draw the UI in the main thread.

Comment: @DougRudd To prevent misunderstanding: to keep the program responsive as can be, I work with TTask. Things that affects UI is being synchronized so that it will be drawn in the main thread.

And sorry that I was not clear. The clock runs in the main thread, there are just other things being progressed in the background (loading xml, pictures, label settings) which, when changes are made to the UI, are being synchronized.

Up to now I have been trying to create a reproducible program but I cant seem to reproduce it. I hoped that someone here knew or had an idea what the issue might have been.