# FireMonkey DirectX canvas ClearType text

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Why Firemonkey doesn't use ClearType when rendering text on D2D canvas? 
I found this question [Cleartype font / text rendering in Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579189/cleartype-font-text-rendering-in-firemonkey)  and after some more research I found after pathing `FMX.Canvas.D2D TCanvasD2D.CreateResources`

```
  If GlobalUseGDIPlusClearType
    then FTarget.SetTextAntialiasMode(D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE_CLEARTYPE)
    else FTarget.SetTextAntialiasMode(D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE_GRAYSCALE);
```

it actually draws ClearType text in test application (some TLabels on the form).

More tests shows that after adding a TMemo (and some other controls)  to the form ClearType suddenly disappears...

Having that, just to test I added the following line to `TTextLayoutD2D.DoDrawLayout`

```
   TCanvasD2D(ACanvas).FTarget.SetTextAntialiasMode(D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE_CLEARTYPE);
```

Now only TLabel is shown properly (with ClearType), but TEdit and TMemo does not draw text at all...

Comment: You might consider to report this as a bug to the quality portal. Possibly somewhere in the TMemo code there is a part that resets the AntiAliasMode.

Comment: @Sherlock70 https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21810?filter=-4 If you wanna vote